# Asp:Label that determined by dropdownlistbox not working properly

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, ssms

This was working the other day, not sure what happened but it isn't now and I cant figure it out. The label will only give me one item out of around 20(give or take) distinct items. No matter what I select in my drop down list, it always gives me that same value on the label.

HTML:

```
                    <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCompanyCode" runat="server" CssClass="Dropdown" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCompanyCode_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="139px" DataSourceID="CompanyCodeDS" DataTextField="CompanyCode" DataValueField="CompanyCode"></asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlCompanyCode" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="*Please select a drop down list item." ForeColor="#CC0000" ValidationGroup="Submit"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblSourceSyst" runat="server" CssClass="txtLabel" Text="Select Company Code" Width="137px" ></asp:Label>
                </td>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="CompanyCodeDS" runat="server" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RptDatamartConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="[AXMap].[SelectCompanyCode_GLSourceCOA]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

C#:

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ddlCompanyCode.Items.Add(new ListItem("--Please Select--", ""));
            ddlCompanyCode.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
        }
    }

    protected void ddlCompanyCode_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RptDatamartConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        String sqlStoredProc = "RptDatamart.AXMap.SelectCompanyCode_GLSourceCOA";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyCode", ddlCompanyCode.SelectedItem.Value);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = sqlStoredProc;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                lblSourceSyst.Text = dataReader["SourceSystem"].ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblStatus.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

And then the stored procedure im trying to use...

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [AXMap].[SelectCompanyCode_GLSourceCOA] 
@CompanyCode varchar(10) = Null,
@SourceSystem nvarchar(255) = Null

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT OFF;

Select distinct CompanyCode, SourceSystem from [RptDatamart].[AXMap].[GLSourceCOA]

END
```

my sql might be terribly off, but i would think it would work.

Answer (score 0):

```
lblSourceSyst.Text = dataReader["SourceSystem"].ToString();
```

Should be:

```
lblSourceSyst.Text += dataReader["SourceSystem"].ToString();
```

Comment: If I do that, it puts all the different items that are in the sourcesystem column into that label at the same time

Comment: Then I'm not sure what you're asking. If you don't want all the items, why are you selecting them all and looping? Also, you aren't using your parameters in the SQL. You pass them, but you don't USE them.

Comment: I want to select the distinct rows for company code and source system. Then put all the company codes into a drop down list, and then when I select something in the ddl, whatever the distinct value is for sourcesystem that goes with it is displayed in the label.

Comment: And right now, the ddl works, but the label is only showing one value that goes with the very last item for the ddl. None of the other values from sourcesystem are being displayed in the label